# AES-256-CBC openssl_encrypt encrypted with PHP and Decryption withJava

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I'm trying to decrypt a string encrypted with this php code :

```
$key = hash('sha256', '0000F6A115DA0C2ADA1234567810ED4E33434ABF3AFB094BB512345678') ;
$data = openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0 , hex2bin('8697C52E5F627E3BB6FA121212121212'));
```

Java decryption code :

```
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary('8697C52E5F627E3BB6FA121212121212'));

MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

SecretKeySpec decryptionKey = new SecretKeySpec(digest.digest("0000F6A115DA0C2ADA1234567810ED4E33434ABF3AFB094BB512345678".getBytes()), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, decryptionKey, iv);

cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText));
```

I got this exception at java side :

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:977)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1058)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:855)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2207)
```

any help or guidance is welcome

Thanks in advance

Comment: [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) returns hexadecimal encoded values by default. Set the raw_output parameter to true.

Comment: thanks @Peter, i'm coding java side so i can't modify php code :(

Comment: Well, then you have to do the hex encoding in Java, throw away the second half of the hash, and live with the fact that you're really only doing AES-128.

Comment: solved, PHP dev added raw_output param and all works fine :) thanks @Peter